# Disable access for database

Tags: mysql, sql, ubuntu, permissions

I created a MySQL server. Now the user `login` has access to all databases. I want this user not to have access (so can't do anything) to 3 databases:

- `information_schema`
- `mysql`
- `phpmyadmin`

So the user can use all databases except these 3. How can I get this done?

Comment: I wrote an [answer on ServerFault about MySQL permissions](http://serverfault.com/questions/258773/vps-set-up-for-mysql/258903#258903). There are tons of resources about doing this sort of thing, but that gives a quick overview of how's and why's

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A brief version of how to do this (which is mostly explained in [the link I posted above](https://serverfault.com/questions/258773/vps-set-up-for-mysql/258903#258903)):

- You need to [`REVOKE` that user's `GLOBAL` privileges](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/revoke.html) - this is because MySQL's privilege system is top-down. If they have a `GLOBAL` privilege to `SELECT` then that applies to *all* of your databases
- You then need to [`GRANT` the correct privileges](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html) on the ones it *does* need access to (you can use wildcards for this)

It's important to note that **MySQL does not have any concept of a "DENY" privilege**.

Comment: Thanks :). `Deny` would have been great though.