# MySQL - Deny a user access to future database

Tags: mysql

For the developer account, I would like to give the access to all feature on all databases plus the right to create new Database ( Since we are using code-first approach) , including the database to-be-created

However, I would like to deny that account's access to database in the form of *.prod, including the database to-be-created ( If Create Table right can also be denied It would be great ! )

Does this requirement make sense for MySQL? Can we achieve that with simple MySQL configuration?

I understand that MySQL [do not provide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5792782/disable-access-for-database) "Deny" privilege. If that is still the case, there is no support for this situation?